# Hadoop Distcp Copy Contents inside directory to directory with same name

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a directory in cluster A: /a/b/c. This directory contains directories "one", "two", "three", ..., "ninety". In cluster B, I have directory /a/b/c. This directory contains directory "one". I want to copy over directories "one" through "ninety" from cluster A to cluster B, so that, finally, cluster B will have directories /a/b/c/one ... /a/b/c/ninety. There were files in cluster B /a/b/c/one that were not in cluster A /a/b/c/one. Those should still be there after the copy.

I have tried the following:

1)

```
distcp /a/b/c/ hdfs:B:8020/a/b/c
```

but this makes a directory c within the previous c.

2)

```
distcp /a/b/c/* hdfs:B:8020/a/b/c
```

but I get:

```
zsh: no matches found: /a/b/c/*
```

3)

```
distcp /a/b/c/\* hdfs:B:8020/a/b/c
```

but I get:

```
Copy failed: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input source /a/b/c/* does not exist.
```

What's the correct command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it.

```
distcp /a/b/c hdfs:B:8020/a/b/
```

Comment: do we need a slash `/` after `/a/b/c` or is it optional?

Comment: But you end up scanning./a/b level.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a "c" as per the proposed scenario, maybe what you want is to add the contents under /a/b/c to the existing /a/b/c in the destination cluster.
For that you can use the -update flag.

```
distcp -update /a/b/c hdfs:B:8020/a/b/c
```